# Android: how to push a picture into the Emulator internal storage ? (not on SD card)

Tags: android, android-emulator, push, directory-structure

Hi there and thanks a lot for your help!

Please I need to push some pictures on the internal storage of the Emulator, so that they can be accessed via MediaStore.Images.Media , INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

Therefore I need them on the internal storage, not the SD card.

Please how do I find the correct directory of the Emulator to push the pictures to?

Thanks a Lot!!!

Comment: Have you tried putting your files in **/data** folder (or its subfolders)?